# Direct Cast giving null error for datagridview

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview, directcast

I am currently working in VB.NET express for desktop, 2013. I am having a hard time binding SQL data to some datagridviews on a loop with an array. I am receiving an object null error and its because on the direct cast line its not pulling the datagridview. I have multiple datagridviews on a tab control tool, one datagridview per tab. Here is my code:

```
 try
 Dim array() As Integer = {"2", "3", "4", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12"}

        For Each value As Integer In array
            Dim RelativeDGV = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DataGridLine" & value), DataGridView)
            Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                conn1.Open()
                Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT LineNumber FROM tableA where LineNumber = @LineNumber", conn1)
                    comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineNumber", value)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                    sql.Fill(dt)
                   RelativeDGV.DataSource = dt
                End Using
                conn1.Close()
            End Using 
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

The error is on line

```
 Dim RelativeDGV = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DataGridLine" & value), DataGridView)
```

But the null error dosen't trigger until

```
  RelativeDGV.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict `"2", "3", "4"` are not integers

Comment: @Plutonix I turned on option strict and changed it too 2, 3, 4, and the code is still bugging on me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Assuming that you have `Option Infer On` then `RelativeDGV` will be of type `DataGridView` (otherwise you should have `Dim RelativeDGV As DataGridView = DirectCast(.....)`). Are you sure that DataGridLine2, DataGridLine3, etc all exist, are of type DataGridView and are members of the form's Controls collection (not inside a `GroupBox` or other container)?

Comment: If you put a break point, you might notice that Me.Controls("DataGridLine" & value) returns a null value. That would mean it can't find it in the list of Controls. The reason might be because your grid isn't in the form but in the tab, so you'll have to search the controls under that tab.

Comment: They are all in a tab control. There is one tab for each of the line numbers and each one holds a datagridview

Comment: @the_lotus that is exactly what I am getting.

Comment: Then replace `Me.Controls` with `MyTab.Controls`, where `MyTab` is the name of the tab containing the `DataGridView`s.

Comment: @Blackwood I changed the code to the mytab.controls and it threw me a null reference error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Then you need to find out what object is a null reference. We can't see your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use list of `DataGridView` like this :

```
Try
    Dim array() As DataGridView = {DataGridLine2, DataGridLine3, DataGridLine4, DataGridLine7, DataGridLine8, DataGridLine10, DataGridLine11, DataGridLine12}
    For Each RelativeDGV As DataGridView In array
        Dim value As Integer = Regex.Replace(RelativeDGV.Name, "[^0-9]+", String.Empty)
        'or like this
        'Dim value As Integer = RelativeDGV.Name.Substring(12, RelativeDGV.Name.Length - 12)
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT LineNumber FROM tableA where LineNumber = @LineNumber", conn1)
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineNumber", value)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                RelativeDGV.DataSource = dt
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: give me a second, im gonna try this. I just need to put a second array in for the "Value" variable in the parameters section that has to change from 2 to 3 to 4 and so on.

Comment: This is working, I have some bugs to work out but its solid.

Comment: @Cheddar Glad to hear that! you can extract value from name of `DataGridView` like answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the various DGV controls are on other tabs, they wont be in `Me.Controls`.  Rather than fish them out and cast them, you can iterate an array of them since you know the name.  You also do not need to create a new connection for each nor duplicate datatables for each:

```
Dim dgvCtrls As DataGridView() = {DataGridLine2, DataGridLine3, DataGridLine4}

Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
    conn1.Open()
    Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT LineNumber FROM...", conn1)
        '    ...
        dt.Load(comm1.ExecuteReader())
    End Using

    conn1.Close()
End Using

For Each dgv In dgvCtrls
    dgv.DataSource = dt
Next
```

You'd only need 8 identical DataTables if you dont want each grid to automatically reflect changes made in the others. For that, use a dataset on the same connection to create the tables:

```
Dim SQL = "..."
Dim dgvCtrls As DataGridView() = {dgv5, dgv2, dgv3,...}
Dim ds = New DataSet

Using dbcon As New SqlConnection(SQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, dbcon)
        dbcon.Open()
        For n As Int32 = 0 To dgvCtrls.Count - 1
            ds.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dgvCtrls(n).Name)
        Next
    End Using
End Using

For Each dgv In dgvCtrls
    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables(dgv.Name)
Next
```